# Displaying the first object in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have an array from php which is converted into object. the object has an object inside it. how can i display only the first object.

tried this.

```
<li v-for="val in CareerLevel.CLLevel">
    <a href="#">{{val}}</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

---

```
{
    "CLLevel":
    {
        "13":
        {
            "Role":["Community Operations New Associate"]
        },
        "12":
        {  
            "Role":["Junior SME","Cross-Skilled Associate","Incubation\/Special Project Associate","Quality Auditor","Trainer","System Developer Associate","Junior SME","System Developer"]
        },
        "11":
        {
            "Role":["Jr. Team Lead\/ Senior SME","Market-Vetical SME","Senior Quality Auditor\/Analyst","Senior Trainer","Policy Analyst","System Developer Analyst","R&C Analyst","policy analyst"]
        },
        "10":
        {
            "Role":["Team Lead","Quality Jr Team Lead","Training Jr Team Lead","Policy Senior Analyst"," System Developer Team Lead"]},"9":{"Role":["Shift Lead"," Senior Team Lead","Quality Lead","Policy Lead","Change Management Lead","R&C Specialist","Training Lead"]
        },
        "8":
        {
            "Role":["Community Operations Market Lead","Local\/Site QTP Lead","Mobilization Lead","Service Management Lead","Global System Developer Lead"," Business Excellence Associate Manager"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `<a href="#">{{ val.Role[0] }}</a>` should display the first element of each "Role" array.

Comment: I assume you want the highest value object (13 in this case). Objects are unordered, so getting the first entry not always work. If you do `Object.keys(CLLevel)` you'll get an array of all the values (`['13','12','11',etc..]`). Find the highest value of those entries and use that as a reference (e.g. `CLLevel[highestVal]`, where highestVal is a string variable with the highest number entry).

Answer (score 0):

In a totally static way, you could do this.

```
<li>{{firstElement}}</li>
```

```
data() {
   return {
      CareerLevel: { /* Your data here */  }
   }
},

computed: {
    firstElement() {
      return Object.values(this.CareerLevel.CLLevel)[0].Role[0]
    }
}
```

To do it "correctly" Id do a recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use computed property for this as you are iterating on an object and wants functionality similar as such as array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data : {
    CareerLevel : {
    "CLLevel":
    {
        "13":
        {
            "Role":["Community Operations New Associate"]
        },
        "12":
        {  
            "Role":["Junior SME","Cross-Skilled Associate","Incubation\/Special Project Associate","Quality Auditor","Trainer","System Developer Associate","Junior SME","System Developer"]
        },
        "11":
        {
            "Role":["Jr. Team Lead\/ Senior SME","Market-Vetical SME","Senior Quality Auditor\/Analyst","Senior Trainer","Policy Analyst","System Developer Analyst","R&C Analyst","policy analyst"]
        },
        "10":
        {
            "Role":["Team Lead","Quality Jr Team Lead","Training Jr Team Lead","Policy Senior Analyst"," System Developer Team Lead"]},"9":{"Role":["Shift Lead"," Senior Team Lead","Quality Lead","Policy Lead","Change Management Lead","R&C Specialist","Training Lead"]
        },
        "8":
        {
            "Role":["Community Operations Market Lead","Local\/Site QTP Lead","Mobilization Lead","Service Management Lead","Global System Developer Lead"," Business Excellence Associate Manager"]
        }
    }
}
  },
  
  computed : {
    firstObj : function(){
      for (var key in this.CareerLevel.CLLevel) {
        if (this.CareerLevel.CLLevel.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return this.CareerLevel.CLLevel[key]
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <a href="#">{{firstObj}}</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS : This will render CLLevel with key 8 as you are using object and they are unordered in nature, no matter how you insert them in object they come out unordered, if you want CLLevel with key 13 to appear than you will have no other choice than to use array as arrays maintain order.